# How to build a slayer exciter

Tags: transistors, diodes, tesla-coil

I am trying to build a slayer exciter.

I am using this diagram from [Instructables:](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Build-a-Slayer-Exciter/step2/The-Driver-Circuit/#step1)

[image]

I changed some components:
- TIP36C(PNP) 
- 5oo turns on secondary coil using magnetic wire(0.8 mm)
- 5 turns on primary coil using normal wires
- 10-20 Vdc
- Resistance 10-30 Kohm

I also changed polarity of primary coil, battery, and diodes (according to many answers on different websites.)

It still doesn't work.

What could be wrong?

Comment: What you should do is use the parts called out on the diagram. To use a TIP36 you would have to have 4 times as many turns on the secondary to get the same output just to start oscillating, and then the voltage would be too high. If you are so limited in parts access perhaps you should choose other projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off all, you should have used the TIP31 NPN transistor as shown in your diagram. Second, the polarity of the windings is not shown but I would try reversing the primary connections before doing a re-build of the project. 
Third, this device MUST arc to its ground (-) connection or have a load connected, or the trigger pulse to the emitter will not occur. This is part of the feedback loop that makes it oscillate continuously.
 *When all else fails, follow the diagram* and build it as shown (reverse the primary wires if it does not arc). The transistor (TIP31C) and diodes (UF4007) were chosen for their specific behaviour, not by guessing or cost considerations. The TIP31 has a gain of about 100, while the TIP36 has a gain of only 25.
**BE CAREFUL!** This is not overwhelming power but it is enough to burn the skin. Use thick gloves to move the high-voltage output wire, which should have plastic tubing over it even though it has some insulation.

Comment: i have some limitations in my country so TIP36c is all i could get ,i already tried to reverse the polarity , i dont understand third part which device ? because there is already ground conneted to emitter,and i am asking because i couldnt get this specific components so i had to resolve it using another ones and try with some knowledge how to modify to make the same functionality :)

Comment: The TIP36c is not a substitute for the TIP31.

Comment: Could you please post a diagram or sketch of what you have built. I could only go by the one you posted and yet you have changed all the parts-and polarity.

Comment: its the same diagram exactly except (battery,diodes) opposite polarity

Comment: @duskwuff can you suggest what can i do ?its the only thing available here in egypt + i made a comparison between both datasheets and all i got is difference in max amp they can hold

Comment: @Sparky256 so to overcome the gain difference i should decrease primary turns and increase input volt ?

Comment: @coding. What you should do is use the parts called out on the diagram. To use a TIP36 you would have to have 4 times as many turns on the secondary to get the same output just to start oscillating, and then the voltage would be too high. If you are so limited in parts access perhaps you should choose other projects.

Comment: @Sparky256 ok last thing, i used 20 Vdc input and i didnt get any output at all not just 1/4 output thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really use the ultra fast recovery diode (UF4007) for the base reverse current diode as the [Chip says](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Build-a-Slayer-Exciter/)? Slayer Exciter does not work satisfactorily if 1N4007 or LED is misused as many example of circuit diagrams are mistaken here. 1N4007 is a diode for low speed 60Hz rectification. Let's be careful.